# File input javascript event, is there an event fire when someone click okay on the dialog box?

Tags: javascript

When someone click on Browse for the input file below:

```
<input type="file" name="blah" />
```

A dialog box will appear. The user will then select a file and click 'Ok'. The dialog box will close. Is there an event fire because of that? I tried onfocus and onblur, it didnt work out.

The only way I can think of is to start a timer to check the value content when it is onfocus. Not that elegant. Any solution?

Cheers,
Mickey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try to listen for an **"onchange"** event on your element.

The only drawback with this is if the user selects the same file using "browse" twice, it wont fire as the contents didnt change but I dont know if that is a requirement in your case.